# Debugging variables not working with gulp sourcemaps + uglify

Tags: javascript, gulp, google-chrome-devtools, gulp-uglify, gulp-sourcemaps

I have the following gulp task for bundling javascript:

```
gulp.task('js', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.js)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(concat('bundle.min.js'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

When I run this in the Chrome dev tools, sourcemaps are found and breakpoints work, **but variables can't be debugged**.

Take this example chunk of angular code:

```
iarApp.config(['$animateProvider', function ($animateProvider) {
    $animateProvider.classNameFilter(/angular-animate/);
}]);
```

If I add a breakpoint to see the value of `$animateProvider`, I get the following:

[image]

But if I turn off variable mangling in Uglify:

```
.pipe(uglify({ mangle: false }))
```

Then it works:

[image]

So it seems that the gulp-sourcemaps plugin can't follow up variables after Uglify mangles the names.

Can anyone else get the same issue and/or know a solution?

Comment: Variables are renamed when the source files are mangled. You can still access the variable but via its mangled name. Adding a source map only helps with finding which line an issue happened on in the actual source, but the variables aren't translated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this is just not possible currently, since this is not part of the specification for source maps.

There are [some](https://github.com/fitzgen/source-map-rfc/blob/scopes-and-bindings/proposals/env.md) [proposals](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.js-sourcemap/BT032gzqhZI) to [add](https://gist.github.com/asterland/edf028ed7947c8c258d1) this feature, so we will have to wait until the spec and implementations are updated.